# How to set global style for a react-select.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I would like to set global style for the [react-select](https://react-select.com/home). For my understanding I can do 2 ways:

1. Using [`className`](https://react-select.com/styles#using-classnames) and `classNamePrefix` and then target elements using CSS.

   **PROS:** I can use the same style everywhere

   **CONS:** Every new component must use exactly the same `className` and `classNamePrefix`

Example:

> className='react-select-container'
>
> classNamePrefix="react-select"

Result:

> ```
> <div class="react-select-container">
>   <div class="react-select__control">
>     <div class="react-select__value-container">...</div>
>     <div class="react-select__indicators">...</div>
>   </div>
>   <div class="react-select__menu">
>     <div class="react-select__menu-list">
>       <div class="react-select__option">...</div>
>     </div>
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```

2. Create external javascript file with [*"Provided Styles and State"*](https://react-select.com/styles#provided-styles-and-state)

   **PROS:** more flexible then CSS

   **CONS:** Every new component must use style property using imported external file.

Example:

> ```
> const customStyles = {
>   option: (provided, state) => ({
>     ...provided,
>     borderBottom: '1px dotted pink',
>     color: state.isSelected ? 'red' : 'blue',
>     padding: 20,
>   }),
>   control: () => ({
>     // none of react-select's styles are passed to <Control />
>     width: 200,
>   }),
>   singleValue: (provided, state) => {
>     const opacity = state.isDisabled ? 0.5 : 1;
>     const transition = 'opacity 300ms';
>
>     return { ...provided, opacity, transition };
>   }
> }
>
>   const App = () => (
>     <Select
>       styles={customStyles}
>       options={...}
>     />
>   );
> ```

What is the best way to style multiple react-select components? Will be possible to set style globally and every new react-select component use that style automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it is to create your own select component like `CustomSelect` that you import instead of `react-select` where you set for one the custom `style` or `theme` like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'

class CustomSelect extends Component {
  render() {

    const styles = {
      ...
      // what ever you need
    }

    return <Select styles={styles} {...this.props} />
  }
}

export default CustomSelect
```

I can't really tell if it's the best way or not but I've tried both of it and in a big project with many select it's the easiest way to maintain / modify it. Plus it's really convenient if at some point you need to have custom components.

Comment: I was thinking about the same approach, and I think you are right it is much flexible way than 2 ways what I provided. Thanks.

Comment: @Observer I would add that more and more in `React` you can see customization through CSS-in-JS and it can be a good practice to reduce the general use of `classes` and traditional CSS